# Multiple aggregate function

Tags: sql, database, plsql

I have the following script -

```
select sum(duration) as duration from opr 
       where op in ('GRC','GCQ')
       and timestamp between '20130101000000' and '20130930235959'
```

I receive the value - **34459298** seconds.
I would like to include these restrictions - The duration which is

- <= '18000000' (seconds)  should be multiplied to 0.14
- The duration between > '18000000' and <= '27000000' should be
  multiplied to 0.11
- and the duration > '27000000'  should be multiplied to 0.09

I have tried with this case statement -

```
   case when duration <= '18000000' 
        then (duration)*0.14
        when duration > '18000000' and duration <= '27000000'
        then (duration)*0.11
        when duration > '27000000' 
        then (duration)*0.09
          else 0 end as bal
```

However, I receive this value **34459298** multiplied to 0.09, because it is bigger then '27000000', which is not the idea.
The idea is all the seconds which these two op ('GRC','GCQ') had made to be multiplied with the above values.

Could you please help me to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is `duration` a number or a string? Would be better to compare with numbers, I guess:

```
SELECT
    SUM(
      CASE
        WHEN duration <= 18000000 THEN duration * 0.14
        WHEN duration > 18000000 AND duration <= 27000000 THEN duration * 0.11
        WHEN duration > 27000000 THEN duration * 0.09
        ELSE 0
      END
    ) AS duration
  FROM opr 
WHERE
  op IN ('GRC','GCQ')
  AND timestamp BETWEEN '20130101000000' AND '20130930235959'
;
```

Answer (score 1):

use subquery to select specific duration and multiply duration by your values and than use sum over that subquery.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select sum(case
        when duration <= '18000000' then (duration)*0.14
        when duration > '18000000' and duration <= '27000000' then (duration)*0.11
        when duration > '27000000' then (duration)*0.09
        else 0
    end) as bal
from opr 
where op in ('GRC','GCQ')
    and timestamp between '20130101000000' and '20130930235959'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do this

```
select sum(case when duration <= '18000000' then (duration)*0.14
                when duration > '18000000' and duration <= '27000000' then (duration)*0.11
                when duration > '27000000' then (duration)*0.09
                else 0 end as bal) as duration 
from opr 
where op in ('GRC','GCQ')
and timestamp between '20130101000000' and '20130930235959'
```